# Direction of eddy current

Tags: electromagnetism

To be honest, this is a homework question. Screenshot of it's given below.

[image]

And the  five choices are given below,

### [image]

**What I already know**

- I know that Eddy current is a  circular electric which is  induced within conductors by a changing magnetic field in the conductor.
- Here the magnetic field is subjected to change, because  the rod is
  made to move towards right

Simply, I am stuck on this question. I can not see a clear pathway to proceed.

So what is your way to approach and solving process for  this question?

Comment: According to Lenz's Law the eddy currents must be induced in such a way as to oppose the motion of the magnet.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice question.

**Explanation 1**:
We know that a circular current produces a magnetic field whose pattern is exactly that of a magnetic dipole:

[image: dipole]

So the sheet simply constructs the currents in answer a to exactly oppose the fields from the bar magnet.

A better and more accurate explanation is the below ones,  which I believe should now tube easier to understand.

**Explanation 2**:
We know from Lenz's law that the currents will oppose the fields generating it.

It will help if you consider the rod stationery for a moment. For a 2d cross section The fields just behind the rod will come out of the sheet, and just in front of it, they go inside.

As the rod moves forward, this field gets weaker. So the currents behind the rod must counter this **CHANGE IN FIELDS**. For the region behind the rod,  the change is a decrease in fields.

Now look at option a. The currents behind attempt to maintain the the status quo. To do this they attempt to increasing the net field. At the front, the change is an increase. So the currents must decrease it. So at the front, the opposite must be true.

At the center the chance is maximum, so the eddy current is the strongest.

So as the rod moves forward the center does too. The fields due to the eddy current decrease behind the rod as the center moves forward, so effectively, their diminishing effect weakens (they attempt to counter the decrease in field by reducing their contribution to the decrease in the net field, ie as per Lenz's law they attempt to increase the field).

At the front they increase their contribution to the decrease in net field by increasing themselves, (closer to centre), the exact opposite of above para.

Note that when I say increase the fields behind the rod,  I simply mean eddy currents decrease their negative contribution to the net field. The net field however will keep on decreasing behind the rod and increase in front of it.

Comment: Hey , could you explain little bit more why the B field behind the  rod reduces and that of forward increases?

Comment: And one more thing, what did you mean by this ===>:, "ABC just in front of it"

Comment: @farsight :what is meant by  "ABC just in front of it"

Comment: ABC was a typo. I added a simpler explanation,  which should help you understand.

Comment: @farsight: Let's move this to a chat